# What is the best way of import modules from complicated path in ESModules

Tags: javascript, node.js

In CommonJS, I use this way.

```
require(constant.APPROOT + "/lib/utils.js")
```

instead of

```
require("../../../../../../lib/utils.js")
```

However, It cannot work in ESModules.

```
import util from constant.APPROOT + "/lib/util.js"
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I know the reason, because it is not static.

I try two way.

[1st] (accept complicated path)

```
import path from "path"
import fs from "fs"
import foo from "./foo.js"
import bar from "../../../../../lib/bar.js"
import util from "../../../../../lib/util.js"

// application code
```

[2nd] (use dynamic import)

```
import path from "path"
import fs from "fs"
import foo from "./foo.js"

!async function main(){
   const [bar, util] = await Promise.all([
       import(constant.APPROOT + "/lib/bar.js"),
       import(constant.APPROOT + "/lib/util.js"),
   ])

   // application code

}()
```

I think that both is not good.
What is the best way?

Comment: 1. Get an IDE with autocompletion/autoimport and stop worrying about the path, or 2. create a single index file that exports everything else, and only import from that one

Comment: You can resolve it with lot of bundle managers such as Webpack. Please tell us if you use any

Comment: I use Node.js. I think that bundle tools are made for browser JavaScript. Should I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Webpack

You could use `webpack` to setup an alias (if you are building a node app then set `target: node` in your config, there are plenty of good guides on how to accomplish this):

```
  resolve: {
    ...,
    alias: {
      '$lib': constant.APPROOT + "/lib"
    }
  }
```

Then import like --> `import util from "$lib/util.js"`

#### 2. Npm Package

You can use this package to setup aliases in package.json --> https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias